# vscode python URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, error-handling

```
# requirements
    
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
ua = UserAgent()
ua.ie
    
req = Request(df["URL"][0], headers={"User-Agent" : ua.ie})
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup_tmp = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup_tmp.find("p", "addy")  #soup_find.select_one(".addy")
```

> URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>

I'm a student who studying python on vscode.
I don't know what I'm missing TT.

df["URL"][0] <- worked ..
anybody help me ..?

+
i solve it !!!!!

```
import requests 
req = requests. get(df["URL"]49, headers={'user-agent' :ua.ie}) 
soup_tmp = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser') 
soup_tmp.select_one('.addy')
```

it works !!!!!!

Comment: What is `df["URL"][0]` ?

Comment: it was just a testing code! I wanted to make sure that "URL" worked.

Comment: Well that is the value of the URL ? The error seems to be related to that.

Comment: it wasn't relevant, and I solved the problem. It was an error of 403. It was a case that the server was intentionally blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the problem is df["URL"][0] in the line:

```
req = Request(df["URL"][0], headers={"User-Agent" : ua.ie})
```

At the same time, you didn't provide the url you used. I used Google to test that it worked well:

```
url='https://www.google.com'
req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent" : ua.ie})
```

You need to check whether the url you use is correct, which is not a problem with the codes.

Comment: Probably i was wrong.. i had to upload the whole part of codes .. It was an error of 403. It was a case that the server was intentionally blocked.